# How can we run WIQL query in Azure devops pipeline task? Any examples

Tags: azure-devops, wiql

I have a pipeline in which I need to query work items for which I am using rest api but I am not sure how to use this with Azure pipeline task.
Mine is a linux agent hence, is it possible to run it in shell instead of powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run [WIQL query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) in shell script or something like that in pipeline task.

Create a Json without newlines like:

```
{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Task' AND [State] <> 'Closed' AND [State] <> 'Removed' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}
```

And send it with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/bin/variables.sh
url="https://dev.azure.com/$(organizationName)/$(project)/_apis/wit/queries/{query}?api-version=7.0"    
response=$(curl -s -u $(presenter):$(PAT) -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "${json}" "${url}")
```

`organizationName` is the organization name.

`project` is the project name.

`presenter` is the user.name (from az account show)

`PAT` is the personal access token.

For running query in PowerShell script with Azure pipeline, you can refer to this ticket [Running query in Pipeline in Azure-DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74673778/running-query-in-pipeline-in-azure-devops).

For running Azure DevOps Service REST API with Linux Shell script, you can refer to this ticket [Create Pull Request by Azure DevOps Service REST API with Linux Shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72445647/create-pull-request-by-azure-devops-service-rest-api-with-linux-shell-script).

Hope that would help you.

Comment: This helped.. Can you also pls tell how can we pass variable values in pipeline?

Comment: You can refer to the doc [Set variables in pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline) and just add variables directly to use throughout the pipeline.